# Avoiding/minimizing git merge conflicts when 2 successive commits edit the same files

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a situation as follows [it's not a concrete programming problem, but something I foresee will happen to me shortly]

1. I am assigned 2 tickets that require adding 2 closely related features, say feature 1 and feature 2 respectively, to a tool. There must 2 separate commits (or 2 distinct set of commits) associated with the addition of these features
2. The addition of both features necessitates editing around 95% of the same source files
3. The changes that need to be introduced to implement feature 2 depend on the changes of feature 1. i.e `if(feature1 flag enabled) foo; else bar;`
4. I just implemented feature1 and sent out a code review, code review turn around is around 2-5 days.I'm sure there will be a few changes suggested by the reviewers
5. However while they are reviewing feature 1 I want to get started with implementing feature 2

How would I go about doing this in a manner that avoid/minimizes painful merge conflicts ? I don't want to check-in/post for review stuff related to feature 2 in the process of addressing review comments for feature 1.

My team uses git, with git flow.

[Not a hypothetical question, actual problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the "*changes that need to be introduced to implement feature 2 depend on the changes of feature 1*", you could start off feature 2 as a branch off of feature 1. This way, you separate addressing of review comments for feature 1 while working on feature 2, and you start working on feature2 with the feature 1 code already in-place in the common files.

Then when the review of feature 1 is completed and it is about to be merged, you can then either:

1. merge feature 1 (to develop, i assume) then rebase feature 2 onto the updated develop

> ```
> develop  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - o (merge feature 1)
>          \                                / \
> feature1  - o - o (for-review) - o (fix) -   \
>                  \                            \
> feature2          - o - o - o - - - - - - - - -o (rebase) - o (continue)
> ```

2. rebase feature 2 onto the final commit for feature 1

> ```
> develop  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - o (merge feature 1)
>          \                                / 
> feature1  - o - o (for-review) - o (fix) -   
>                  \                \
> feature2          - o - o - o - - - o (rebase) - o (continue)
> ```

Note that this will not *completely* avoid conflicts. If the review comments for feature1 required some refactoring of common code or a complete redesign of the implementation, then rebasing feature2 will certainly introduce conflicts, but at least it's localized in the feature2 branch.  But in the cases where the comments are mostly syntactical or, for example error-handling was added etc., then there shouldn't be any problems with the rebase.